# change an object variable from other object(delegation)

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I am using python to implement something like following.

sample1.py

```
Class D:
    def __ini__(self):
        return  

    def disconnect(self):
        ## I want to change isConnected in A, but I can not do something like A.isConnected = False here. I want to use delegation.
        return
```

sample2.py

```
Class B(A):
    Class C(D):
         def _init_(self):
             super(B.C,self)._init_()

         def foo():
             if self.isConnected:
                print "error"

    def __init__(self):

        super(C, self).__init__()
```

sample3.py

```
Class A(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.isConnected = False
```

Whenever D.disconnect() is executed, I want to change A.isConnected value. If i am not allowed to call A.isConnected = False. How can I use delegation to achieve my goal.

It would be great if you can provide some hints or suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: If `A` is created in the same scope that `C`'s class is defined, then you only need to do `A.a = whatever` in the `c` function. If that doesn't work for you, please describe your current design more thoroughly.

Comment: I edited my question and add sample code

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on your objective. Sounds like you want to edit a variable before it is created.

If that is not the case, you should be able to change A.isConnected with the following code:

`A.isConnected = True`